# Complex ef core 2.1 query produces null reference exception how we find what is causing the problem

Tags: ef-core-2.1

I have a complex query that is give a null reference exception:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

An example of the complex query would be a car manufacturer, that must deliver cars to a dealership on a particular date.
So we have a car:

```
public class Car
```

{
        public int CarId { get; set; }

```
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public int? CarActionDefId { get; set; }

    public CarActionDef CarActionDef { get; set; }

}
```

public class ActionDef
{
    public int ActionDefId { get; set; }

```
public string Name { get; set; }

public List<ActionSchedules> ActionSchedules { get; set; }
```

}

public class CarActionDef
{
    public int CarActionDefId { get; set; }

```
public int CarId { get; set; }

public int ActionDefId { get; set; }

public Car Car { get; set; }

public ActionDef ActionDef { get; set; }
```

}

public class ActionSchedule
{
    public int ActionScheduleId { get; set; }

```
public DateTime? NextDue { get; set }

public int ActionDef_RID { get; set }

public virtual ActionDef ActionDef { get; set }
```

}

Understand this is pseudo code to give you an idea of what is occurring.
If we want to get the cars that are scheduled for delivery between a start and end date we use a query like this:

```
            res =
                context.Cars.
                    Include ( g => CarActionDef ).
                    Include ( g => g.CarActionDef.ActionDef ).
                    Include ( g => g.CarActionDef.ActionDef.ActionSchedules ).
                    Where ( g => g.CarActionDef != null && g.CarActionDef.ActionDef != null &&
                                 g.CarActionDef.ActionDef.ActionSchedules != null &&
                                 g.CarActionDef.ActionDef.ActionSchedules.Count > 0 ).
                    Where ( g => g.CarActionDef.ActionDef.ActionSchedules [ 0 ].NextDue != null &&
                                 g.CarActionDef.ActionDef.ActionSchedules [ 0 ].NextDue >= startDate &&
                                 g.CarActionDef.ActionDef.ActionSchedules [ 0 ].NextDue <= endDate ).
                    OrderByDescending ( g => g.CarActionDef.ActionSchedules [ 0 ].NextDue ).
                    Select ( g => g ).
                    ToList ();
```

However when we execute this statement we get a null reference exception. We have tested the method to get any CarActionDef for a car that is null 
and we get an empty collection. Likewise we tried CarActionDef.ActionDef and CarActionDef.ActionDef.ActionSchedules and both collection returned were
empty. So debugging to find a problem navigation property or list has produced nothing and there is no inner exception. Is there some way we can find what 
is causing the null reference exception?

Comment: Check for client evaluation warnings. Most likely the indexer (`ActionSchedules [ 0 ]`) is causing client evaluation, and at that time navigation properties are not loaded yet (although they will be later when applying `Include`s). Client evaluation won't be supported in EF Core 3.0 anyway, so try rewriting the query w/o using indexer, or insert `.AsEnumerable()` before the second `.Where` to force switching to LINQ to Objects context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use then include

```
`res =  context.Cars.Include ( g => CarActionDef )
.ThenInclude ( f => f.ActionDef )
.ThenInclude ( t => t.ActionSchedules )`
```

Comment: I am not sure how this will help. We have the same includes in other statements using the same includes and everything works. The only thing different is the where statement